# gradle maven publish plugin : unable to upload zip via `publish`

Tags: gradle, deployment, archive, maven-publish

I am trying to write a `build.gradle` for my Spring boot Application.(gradle v.`6.5.1`)

After build, I want to deploy it to the private Nexus repo.(with asset zip file)

The problem is... When I execute command `gradle build publish --debug`, It uploads the bootJar, but not asset zip file. And there are no suspicious messages in the console.

Here is the part of the `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "maven-publish"
}

task assembleAssets(type:Zip) {
    archiveFileName = "${rootProject.name}-${rootProject.version}.zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("${buildDir}/libs/")
    from "assets"
    classifier "assets"
}
tasks.build.dependsOn(assembleAssets)

# From bootJar
configurations {
    [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
        it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar) }
        it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {

        bootJarDeploy(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }

        assetDeploy(MavenPublication) {
            artifact source: assembleAssets, extension: 'zip', classifier: 'config'
        }
    }
    repositories {

        maven {
            url = "${nexus_url}"
            credentials {
                username repoUser
                password repoPw
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked Zip file generation in local directory and uploaded jar(bootJar) in Nexus UI. But There is no zip file in Nexus...

**I would like to upload my zip archive file to Nexus.**

Is there something I missed or simply it is not good to use `maven-publish` plugin with `bootJar`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below publishes zip file

```
task zipJ(type: Zip, dependsOn: jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

build.dependsOn zipJ

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            //from components.java
            artifact jar
            artifact zipJ
        }
    }
}
```